# Serve different assets depending Modernizr

Tags: node.js, express, modernizr

I'm setting up a new node.js server, and I want to send to the user different web pages/assets depending on the response of the Modernizr library.

This is a Windows server, it uses express basic commands to show files. Some browsers don't allow .webp images so I decided to include Modernizr to detect if this technology is allowed or no so the server gives you a .png or a .webp that are located in different folders.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var Modernizr = './path/to/lib/modernizr.js';

function image() {
   Modernizr.on('webpanimation', function( result ) {
  if (result) {
    return "__dirname + '/webp'";
      }
  else {
    return "__dirname + '/png'";
  }
})
}

app.use('/', express.static(image()));

// app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/webp'));  (This works)   

app.listen(3000);
console.log("I'm here, in port 3000");
```

When you run it gives you an error.

```
C:\Users\marke\Desktop\node>node app.js
C:\Users\marke\Desktop\node\app.js:10
        Modernizr.on('webpanimation', function( result ) {
                  ^

TypeError: Modernizr.on is not a function
    at image (C:\Users\marke\Desktop\node\app.js:10:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marke\Desktop\node\app.js:24:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

I have various theories, one of them is that maybe the path of Modernizr is wrong although I can't find any other way to ask for it as I can't use require.

Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared Modernizr variable to be a **string** , as far as I see.

```
var Modernizr = './path/to/lib/modernizr.js';
...
Modernizr.on()...
```

Did you mean:

```
var Modernizr = require('./path/to/lib/modernizr.js');
```

?